# Real and steady hash of object

Tags: php, oop

I need to clearly identify an object and store it's identification within my DB.
Afterwards i need this ID to restore this object back.

I tried using "spl_object_hash()" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) but this function returns another value each time I reload the page.

For testing, this objects is steady and stays the same and completely unchanged. Never the less "spl_object_hash()" returns different results time and time again I do a reload.

```
$foo = new stdClass();
print_r(spl_object_hash($foo));
```

-> another hash every time I hit refresh

I need a way to creates a hash depending on the complete object. This hash should not change as long as the object does not.

I don't want to implement an own method (as long as there is no other possibility for solving my problem) for this, for I need a quick, easy and uniform way to identify my objects.

Further more I don't want to use Sessions for this purpose.

So what can I do to workaround this Problem?

Thanks ahead & friendly regards!

Comment: what about a simple md5(serialize($foo));

Comment: *"Note that the contents (properties) of the object are NOT hashed by the function, merely its internal handle and handler table pointer. This is sufficient to guarantee that any two objects simultaneously co-residing in memory will have different hashes. Uniqueness is not guaranteed between objects that did not reside in memory simultaneously."* - first comment in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php#76220).  The inference being that this function isn't designed to produce the same result for an object between sessions.

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch: wow, this is perfectly what I need and it embarrasses me that I did not come to this by my self. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Emissary: thank you for this digression. I will note that. It makes some things crystal clear. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use serialize call (with overriden __sleep() magic call) to serialize the object, to get a unique hash :

```
$hash = md5(serialize($myObject));
```

Plus in objects where you store some extra data (like PDO handler, file handle) you can overwrite __sleep() and __wakeup() methods to get/set only object data, for example code from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep

```
<?php
class Connection
{
    protected $link;
    private $dsn, $username, $password;

    public function __construct($dsn, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $this->link = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
    }

    public function __sleep()
    {
        return array('dsn', 'username', 'password');
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }
}?>
```

this should give you a good hash of object, and even better, you can configure which fields you want to use to create hash.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what Jens-AndréKoch previously suggested. Its exactly what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do this :

```
function object_hash($object, $algorithm = 'md5') {
    $serialized_object = serialize($foo);

    return hash($algorithm, $serialized_object);
}

$foo = new stdClass();
print_r(object_hash($foo));
```

Comment: That's what I did not want to do. I also could have added a Method to my class which returns a perfectly unique ID, but I did not want to write an method my self to keep everything most tiny as possible. That's why I was searching for a quick one-liner way.

Comment: @serjoscha - but adding a method to class is also very good option. You can create a Interface called let say "IUniqueIdentifierProvider" with one method "getUniqueID()", and then in all you objects you can expect the IUniqueIdentifierProvider instance.

This will add a lot of clarity to your project and help you maintain the code dependencies.